# ASP.NET Development Web Server broke

Tags: asp.net, web-services, .net-2.0, webserver

I had VS 2005 with v2.0 of the framework. Then I installed NDoc recently and that supports only v1.1, so it installed v1.1 on top of v2.0. That is fine because both versions can co-exist but what it did was screw up some settings with:

a) The web server that comes with ASP.NET, the one you run your web services on in debug mode.

b) SQL Server's active CLR settings (but this isn't bothering me as much)

c) IIS settings (but I fixed this by re-registering IIS with 2.0)

What's bothering me to the hilt now is the broken ASP.NET web server won't allow me to debug my Web services or even have another project in the same solution create a web reference to it.

I can't generate proxies in Visual Studio because of this, nor can I set a web reference to a web service in the same solution (as it involves generating a proxy).

Note that I can call wsdl.exe though. But I don't want to deploy my service yet. I just want all projects in the same solution referencing the ws like well-behaved little kids.

When I do try to create a web reference to the WS project in my solution, I keep getting this error:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'DaWS.PhoneDirectory'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="PhoneDirectory.asmx.cs" 
Line 2:  Class="DaWS.PhoneDirectory" %>

Source File: /PhoneDirectory.asmx    Line: 2

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3082; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082

It's been nagging me for days now and I've been managing with deploying in IIS.

Other than re-install Visual Studio, does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new web service, and do not change it at all. See if it works.

BTW, the fact that this page displays .NET 2.0 and not 1.1 suggests version is not the problem.

Comment: That code above was for a sample new Web service. It happens with all Web services -- old or the new ones I create.

Comment: Ok, but did you touch it at all after you created it?

Comment: Also, did you build the service before you tried to create a web reference to it?